# show html table inside tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**FULL Code here:** https://jsfiddle.net/zw9sy5ew/2/

this code will generate two tables based on JSON keys,.

How do i create **Jquery tabs** and put the first table in one tab and the other table in another tab

```
$.each(data.user, function(key, value) {
    var row = $("<tr/>");
    if ($('table#main_table_' + value.id).length)
        table = $("#main_table_" + value.id);
    else
        table = $('<table></table>');
        table.attr('id', 'main_table_' + value.id);
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.name));
        row.append($("<td/>").text(value.id));
        table.append(row);
        $("#list_table_json").append(table);
        $("#list_table_json").append("<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables grouped by value.id:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test jQuery Tabs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="ul-tabs">

  </ul>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = $.parseJSON("{\"version\":\"5.2\",\"user_type\":\"online\",\"user\":[{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"Mark\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"Johnny\",\"id\":57}]}");

const setTables = new Set();
$.each(data.user, function(key, value) {
  let table;
  var row = $("<tr/>");

  if ($('table#main_table_' + value.id).length)
    table = $("#main_table_" + value.id);
  else
    table = $('<table></table>');
  table.attr('id', 'main_table_' + value.id);

  row.append($("<td/>").text(value.name));
  row.append($("<td/>").text(value.id));

  table.append(row);

  if(!setTables.has(value.id)) {
    setTables.add(value.id);
    $( "#ul-tabs" ).append("<li><a href=\"#tabs-"+ value.id +"\">"+value.id+"</a></li>");
    $( "#tabs" ).append("<div id=\"tabs-"+value.id+"\">"+table.prop('outerHTML')+"</div>");
  }
});

$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You :) How do i add an <th>Name</th> and  <th>ID</th> ?

Comment: Hello :) Just after creating the table, add a thead to it in this way: table.append( $("<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Id</th></tr></thead>") );

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d19918/nz1yc3x0/1/ fiddle link of your code, is there a way i can give some "text" like user 1 and user 2 instead of id's 50 and 57

Comment: Just check this line:

$( "#ul-tabs" ).append("<li><a href=\"#tabs-"+ value.id +"\">"+value.id+"</a></li>");

and replace the second value.id that is before </a> with anything you want

Answer (score 1):

I took an example from JQuery ui tabs and I modified it for your needs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test jQuery Tabs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="ul-tabs">

  </ul>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = $.parseJSON("{\"version\":\"5.2\",\"user_type\":\"online\",\"user\":[{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"Mark\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"Johnny\",\"id\":57}]}");

$.each(data.user, function(key, value) {
  let table;
  var row = $("<tr/>");

  if ($('table#main_table_' + value.id).length)
    table = $("#main_table_" + value.id);
  else
    table = $('<table></table>');
  table.attr('id', 'main_table_' + value.id);

  row.append($("<td/>").text(value.name));
  row.append($("<td/>").text(value.id));

  table.append(row);

  console.log(table);

  $( "#ul-tabs" ).append("<li><a href=\"#tabs-"+ value.name +"\">"+value.name+"</a></li>");
  $( "#tabs" ).append("<div id=\"tabs-"+value.name+"\">"+table.prop('outerHTML')+"</div>");
});

$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you saved my day, could you share the jquery ui tabs examples link and the output of your code shows three tabs, where john and mark share same data.. how to make it only two tabs

Comment: The JQuery UI link is jqueryui.com/tabs
I understood that you want to group by value.id, so I'm going to send you a different working solution and you can choose the one you like better